# How to divide adjacent items in a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have a list of integers, and I would like to divide the i+1 element by the i element, creating a new list. How can I do this?

The only way I could think of doing it is to zip together adjacent elements into tuples, and then divide them.

```
adj xs = zip xs $ tail xs
```

Comment: You could use `zipWith` for this, which would eliminate the need to convert to tuples first.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I needed.

`zipWith (/) (tail a) a`